# UIImagePickerController to take photo with out asking for "use" confirmation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

Im building an app that takes a photo of the user, its working fine

using the nice UIImagePickerController

this is what happens when the button that calls the delegate for the UIImagePickerController gets called

1. open camera modal view to take image
2. tap on the camera [bottom bar] to take the pic
3. bottom bar with: Retake (left side); Use (right side)

but my question and what i need is:

1. open camera modal view to take image
2. tap on the camera [bottom bar] to take the pic
3. save that pic, "Use", with out asking confirmation

thanks a lot!

Comment: you will need to bake your own camera view if this is the behaviour you need. Apple provides an AVFoundation sample project which should get you started, but be aware that it is a lot more work than what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a `cameraOverlayView` and set `showsCameraControls = NO`.

EDIT: removed ref to `allowEditing`.

Comment: hi, thanks, yes i already tried that, but the "allowEditing", is for moving scaling the image once is taken

Comment: if that's the case, you need to provide your own `cameraOverlayView` and set `showsCameraControls=NO`. Sorry, I was going off the top of my head, I've been doing custom cameras so don't use UIImagePicker anymore (use AVCaptureSession instead).

Comment: Haha, i was looking for this in the opposite point of view. I dont get the editting window and i was wondering why, and thats cuz i have my own overlay and controls off.